# Git - graft branch onto master below current HEAD (branch was created from master below HEAD)

Tags: git, git-branch

I created a feature branch from master at HEAD~5.

I committed changes to the branch and am now happy with the contents of the branch (and I don't want the changes contained in the commits made to master beyond the point where I made the branch).

So this is what I've got.

```
master   A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I
               \
feature          J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R
```

So what I'd like to do throw away the last three commits to master and then add the commits made to the feature branch so that I end up with this

```
master   A-B-C-D-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R
```

Before the branch was created all of the master commits were pushed to the remote repos. I am the only person who interacts with the local and the remote repos.

---

**HEALTH WARNING**

To anyone reading this question and considering making use of the advice please be sure to read all the comments as I had a very particular circumstance which might not necessarily be your circumstance.

The change made to the repos is not one that you're going to easily come back from and if there is more than one local repos in use things are going to get weird for the other local repos.

Comment: Note that it appears you are throwing away the five latest commits `F` through `I` made to the `master` branch.  Is this what you really want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, that's correct. The last few commits to master need to be disposed of and the all of the commits made to 'feature' need to be grated onto master after the point at which the branch was made..

Comment: Then my answer below is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you may simply reset `master` to the `feature` branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard feature
```

However, the above solution rewrites the history of the `master` branch, and should probably be avoided if this branch be shared by anyone other than yourself.

Comment: OK thanks. So can I just clarify what's this is going to do ? The 'git reset --hard feature' effectively replaces 'master' with the contents of 'feature' ?

Comment: Just to confirm that I am the only person who interacts with either the local or the remote repos.

Comment: Yes, but since you want `master` to look exactly like `feature`, the logic is correct.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want it's just seeing it written out like that just made me want to check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Absolutely but I just want to actually execute the command and I can't do that for a little while. I will certainly mark the answer as correct after that, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks this works fine. The only thing I would add is that after having done the 'git reset --hard feature' it was, of course, necessary to 'push' but git didn't like doing a plain old push and and a 'git push --force' was necessary.

Comment: @glaucon Yes, exactly, and this is precisely why this answer should be avoided on shared branches, because it _rewrites_ history.

Comment: Or just `git checkout -B master feature`.